# How to recognize russian text from images by using Tesseract OCR code?

Tags: excel, vba, text, ocr, tesseract

I'm using this code for Microsoft Excel to recognize english text and numbers from .jpg files (images), it works correctly:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Tesseract_OCR()
    Dim strCommand As String, strImagePath As String, strOcrResult As String
    Dim ws As Object

Set ws = VBA.CreateObject("wscript.shell")

strImagePath = GetImageFullPath()

If Not IsEmpty(strImagePath) Then
    **strCommand = "cmd.exe /c tesseract """ & strImagePath & """ stdout -l eng"
    strOcrResult = ws.Exec(strCommand).StdOut.ReadAll**
    Range("A1").Value = strOcrResult
End If
End Sub

Function GetImageFullPath() As String
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Dim strFile As String

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Images", "*.png, *.jpg"
    .Title = "Choose an Image"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = True Then
       strFile = .SelectedItems(1)
       GetImageFullPath = strFile
    End If
End With
End Function
```

But when i try to recognize russian text, either i get weird symbols or nothing at all as a result.

I try to change code into this, expecting to get russian text in excel sheet in result:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Tesseract_OCR()
    Dim strCommand As String, strImagePath As String, strOcrResult As String
    Dim ws As Object

Set ws = VBA.CreateObject("wscript.shell")

strImagePath = GetImageFullPath()

If Not IsEmpty(strImagePath) Then
**    strCommand = "cmd.exe /c tesseract """ & strImagePath & """ stdout -l rus --oem 1 --psm 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ"**
    strOcrResult = ws.Exec(strCommand).StdOut.ReadAll
    Range("A1").Value = strOcrResult
End If
End Sub

Function GetImageFullPath() As String
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Dim strFile As String

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Images", "*.png, *.jpg"
    .Title = "Choose an Image"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show = True Then
       strFile = .SelectedItems(1)
       GetImageFullPath = strFile
    End If
End With
End Function
```

I also downloaded russian tesseract library into tessdata folder. Nothing helps. The only information i get is either numbers, or nothing at all.

I'd be grateful, if you help me.